# jquery cant read textfield value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a problem today with some codes regarding reading textfield value.
the value is returned back to the page as the result of a query from a php file:
//the first text filed with event calling a php file to query the name's order in the list.

```
<label for=name>Name</label>
<input id=name name=name type=text placeholder="Individual / Company Director" required onblur="getOrderInList();" >
```

the function getOrderInList() does a query and sends the result back to the caller page using javascript

```
parent.document.getElementById('customerorder')=document.getElementById('query_result');
```

the query result which is an integer, is supposed to be back to the main page where the name text field is in a specific hidden text box `customercode`

using jQuery i need to show it on the page using an alert for example. but seems to be `undefined`.

can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

your code is in javascript and you are mentioning jquery in your question. its a bit confusing but my guess is you need your javascript code to be corrected

```
parent.document.getElementById('customerorder').value = document.getElementById('query_result').value;
```

Comment: Since I have intruduced the jquery library to the file, it is ok and i have tested both sort of codes and they work fine! I

Answer (score 1):

**In JavaScript:**

```
parent.document.getElementById('customerorder').value = document.getElementById('query_result').value;
```

**In jQuery:**

```
   $('#customerorder').val( $('#query_result').val() )
```

Comment: + for covering the missing jq